# Is it appropriate to Edit an answer just to improve the answer-er?

Tags: discussion

Regarding this little gem from a 19k user:

> @Jon instead of improving your answer I decided to write my own. –  Philipp Apr 27 at 11:43

And this question: [Editing the pixels of a rendered image](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/100531/editing-the-pixels-of-a-rendered-image)

I left a comment stating that he should expand his answer.
I'm wondering if it's also appropriate to suggest an edit to his answer, like so:

**[EXPAND: Does BlendState matter?]**

I know that it does, and the answerer probably does to, but it was omitted in lieu of a one-liner and youtube tutorial link.

I don't want to be like Philipp; I want to **help** the user improve his own answer. When Philipp suggested that I expand on my answer, I didn't even know there **was** another way to do it; I needed Philipp's knowledge as much as the OP. If he had taken the time to list all 2 of the methods, I would have realized that I was out of my depth, **asked** him to post an answer that I could up-vote, and removed mine, if he agreed.

Comment: [Philipp's original comment](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99060/how-to-design-ai-to-understand-its-selling-decisions/99061#comment174151_99061) on your answer was perfectly reasonable. He was simply suggesting you provided a more theoretical explanation of your code. This seems to be more in line with what the OP wanted as well, since they did not specify a language they were probably looking for a high-level explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> Regarding this little gem from a 19k user:

There is nothing wrong with adding one's *own* answer to a question rather than improve an existing one and users are under no obligation to favor improvement over new posts, for a variety of reasons. There's nothing eyebrow-raising whatsoever in Philipp's decision.

> I left a comment stating that he should expand his answer.

This is good (although it might be considered bad form by some to explicitly "bribe" a user with votes in exchange for improvement, as you did in your original comment).

> I'm wondering if it's also appropriate to suggest an edit to his
>   answer, like so:

No, it isn't. Edit an answer to *improve* it, not to embed commentary within it that it should be improved. That's what comments are for. Editing to improve answers should not fundamentally change or add significant content to (non-wiki) answers.

If you've got an edit in mind that adds a lot of content, it probably *is* better off as a new answer.

> I know that it does, and the answerer probably does to, but it was
>   omitted in lieu of a one-liner and youtube tutorial link.

One-liner tutorial links are the definition of "link only" answers and should be actively discouraged/voted-down/voted-for-deletion.